# How would you work around the possible regression in Firefox 81 that breaks "javascript:" URL with "target='_blank'"?

Tags: javascript, html, url, firefox, browser

I have a website, where the home page has an anchor linking a `javascript:` URL that is supposed to open in a new tab, and that in turn, is supposed to open a `mailto:` URL, which is supposed to open a selection for an email client, or directly open the default email client. However the link isn't parsed and handled. The link isn't being navigated to in Firefox 80, 81, 82, 83, and maybe earlier or later versions. Works as expected on Microsoft Edge and older versions of Firefox such as 70.0. Probably also work in Chrome, not tested. Is there a workaround for Firefox, that doesn't break cross-browser support?

I'm using a `javascript:` URL instead of using a `mailto:` address directly, because there is a requirement to obfuscate the email address in order to prevent email harvesting.

I have been able to reduce the code to the following, which is supposed to popup an alert box:

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello!')" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Note: The above simplified example doesn't show the entire original requirement. It just demonstrates the nature of the bug. `javascript:` combined with `target="_blank"`, is what causes the issue.

Link to [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1667009)

A workaround already suggested is removing the `target="_blank"` attribute. This would, however, cause the original (home) page to be replaced when the link is clicked, which is undesirable. Therefore, I don't believe it's a proper workaround, though maybe better than nothing.

The original implementation has since been changed into a PHP based solution, which is even more secure and robust, and works around the bug, so I have removed the link as not applicable to the question anymore.

Comment: 'is anything wrong with the JavaScript': it is human-unreadable.

Comment: @MartinJames, Thanks for your response. At least you commented. I thought it should be presented in it's original form as it might affect the behavior. I wasn't sure if the encoding was the problem. But I'll try to add decoded version as well. Thanks.

Comment: @MehBMe If you're worried about revealing some domain name, you can use "example.com".

Comment: @AndrewMorton, This script doesn't just hide a domain name, it hides a full email address, but allows navigating to the mailto: version of that email address. Even if it were just a domain name, it would have to be navigateable to. The user wouldn't want to navigate to example.com. Or, were you referring to my reluctance to decode the script any further?

Comment: @MehBMe Yes, I was referring to your reluctance to decode the script further. If you use "test@example.com" as the email address it will not be delivered anywhere. In the *actual* code you would use the real email address, but for public display here it is OK to use example.com and everyone will know what you mean.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Thanks for the suggestion, but as per EDIT 3, the issue was found to be a change in Firefox behavior between versions. So no more need to decode ;)

Comment: [Question formation in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s) (QUASM). Missing auxiliary (or helping) verb - either drop the question mark or use the helper verb, e.g. - *"How do I ... ?"* or *"How can I ... ?"*

Answer (score 3):

These suggestions mostly focus on opening a `javascript:` URL which possibly then opens a `mailto:` URL without replacing the original document/page. These solutions were tested with Firefox 81 on Windows.

I tried inserting snippets, but I couldn't get the links to work, so I'm instead using code samples.

#### Method 1A

```html
<a href="javascript:open('mailto:user@example.net','Send Email','width=1,height=1'),document.documentElement.outerHTML">Email Me!</a>
```

This is just for reference: It doesn't exactly work around the bug, but it is still relevant. It's sort of a control case. A new popup window will be opened, and then the `mailto:` address will be opened, but the content of the original document will be replaced with the same content. The content will be preserved, but the behavior is likely to break.

#### Method 1B

```html
<a href="javascript:open('mailto:user@example.net','Send Email','width=1,height=1'),'<script>location.reload()</script>'">Email Me!</a>
```

Not a workaround: Another control case. After opening the new window and then opening the `mailto:` address, the original page will be reloaded/refreshed. This will preserve the behavior, but the current state is likely to be reset.

#### Method 2

```html
<a href="javascript:open('javascript:location=\'mailto:user@example.net\'','Send Email','width=1,height=1'),document.documentElement.outerHTML">Email Me!</a>
```

This is a workaround that can be used to open a `javascript:` URL without losing all of the original page content.

#### Method 3

```html
<a href="javascript:open('mailto:user@example.net','_self','width=1,height=1'),document.documentElement.outerHTML">Email Me!</a>
```

This also isn't a workaround for the bug, but demonstrates a way to open a `mailto:` URL without replacing the original page and also without opening a JavaScript popup. The '_self' option indicates the original window will be used.

#### Method A: iframe

```html
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('i').src='mailto:user@example.net',document.documentElement.outerHTML">Email Me!</a>
<iframe id="i" style="width:0;height:0;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

As can be seen, this requires a hidden iframe element. This can be alternatively done without using the `javascript:` URI and instead using a click (onclick) event handler.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('i').src='mailto:user@example.net',document.documentElement.outerHTML;event.preventDefault()">Email Me!</a>
<iframe id="i" style="width:0;height:0;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

You may also use the `addEventLister()` function to attach an event.

#### Method B: iframe

```html
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('i').src='javascript:location=\'mailto:user@example.net\'',document.documentElement.outerHTML">Email Me!</a>
<iframe id="i" style="width:0;height:0;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Again, a click event handler may be used.

#### Method 4

```html
<a href="javascript:open('javascript:location=\'mailto:user@example.net\'','_self','width=1,height=1'),document.documentElement.outerHTML">Email Me!</a>
```

Strangely, it only works after invoking above iframe method, and it needs further investigation.

This isn't an exhaustive list. Also, there are some data: URI alternatives. Data URIs are blocked from being opened at the top level in modern browsers. They do work in popup windows and iframes.

You may be able to mix and match elements from some of these solutions to get a solution suitable for your specific requirements...

Comment: No idea why you simply don't set the href to the `mailto:` protocol string and let browser do it's default action passing to mail client. All these workarounds seem overkill for a simple issue when using mailto in an href properly

Comment: @charlietfl, You may understand the reason, if you saw what I was trying to achieve originally. It was an attempt to obfuscate the email address so it isn't harvested. I didn't go into those details in this answer, because it would take a lengthy explanation, and not sure I would express it right. But the initial version of the question above, linked to a website. There, you can see the obfuscated URL in action.

Comment: Ok..I remember now and was also part of the "toxic" discussion on Meta about original closure. You could just use addEventListener and decode the obfuscated address to pass to location without needing frame or other window. Note this is a far better outline of what the problem actually is than the first version of the question that got closed, although the bit with alert in question still doesn't outline the mailto issue and really no idea why a mailto would need target blank

Comment: @charlietfl, The relevant points are: "without replacing the original document/page" and "javascript: URL". A javascript: or data: URI is required to support the obfuscation. However, a javascript: URL causes the original page content to be replaced. As noted: "This would, however, cause the original (home) page to be replaced when the link is clicked, which is undesirable.".

Comment: Huh? not with a mailto. Page shouldn't be affected

Comment: @charlietfl, No, it can't be just a simple mailto:. It has to be javascript: to support the obfuscation. I don't think there's a way to obfuscate a direct mailto:

Comment: Right but if you do the decoding in a click handler all this other stuff is not needed. Just click and decode and pass to location object and new email should open. You have done all these more complex solutions but not the easiest way

Comment: @charlietfl, If the decode logic is embedded as JavaScript in the document, or in an included JavaScript file, it can be done as you say, but the idea was to create a self-contained URL that could be used anywhere, and that could be changed/substituted for a different one at any time, easily. You could say it was an attempt to decouple the decode logic. The iframe solutions above also tightly couple the decode logic to the page, which is a bit less than optimal.

Comment: Well what about when a human opens the email ... can simply copy the decoded address from the *"To'* field. The only way to completely keep it out of reach is to use a proxy on server to send the mail

Comment: @charlietfl, That's an acceptable limitation. This isn't intended to prevent someone from manually getting hold of the email. This type of solution just deters automated harvesting of emails, using web crawlers. This isn't a novel solution, BTW. Others do this type of obfuscation of email addresses. It's a bit better than just writing "user (at) example (dot) net" and such, especially since this allows click navigation.

Comment: I have read somewhere that there was one instance at least where google associated something with someone's email address they had made available on their website in obfuscated javascript form.